# Best way to do several calls to http get request?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httprequest

what's the best way to do several http-get-request calls (HttpURLConnection execute) from my MainActivity?

Should I do:

```
    HttpGetRequest getRequest1 = new HttpGetRequest(); // Instantiate new class instance
    AsyncTask<String, Void, String> result1 = getRequest.execute(parameters1);
    HttpGetRequest getRequest2 = new HttpGetRequest(); // Instantiate new class instance
    AsyncTask<String, Void, String> result2 = getRequest.execute(parameters2);
```

... or:

```
    HttpGetRequest getRequest = new HttpGetRequest(); // Instantiate new class instance
    AsyncTask<String, Void, String> result1 = getRequest.execute(parameters1);
    result2 = getRequest.execute(parameters2);
```

I suppose the second option is the best, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

After many (un)successfull tries, I came to the conclusion that the best way is to create a new HttpGetRequest() for each request, so first option!